# Преобразование логического выражения из дизъюнктивной в конъюнктивную форму

Tags: логика

Надо привести выражение в конъюнктивную форму .
Прилагаю рисунок с пейнта с моей попыткой. Начал преобразовывать и получил дизъюнктивную форму , правильно ли я дальше перевел ее в конъюнктивную?
Очень извиняюсь за плохой почерк в пейнте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что надо привести в конъюнктивную форму 
( ¬P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ ( P ∧ Q)

или если с самого начала 
( ¬P ->Q ) -> ( P ∧ Q)

Comment: а что, в пейнте компонент "Text" отменили? А в мире?

Comment: Проще написать на бумажке и сфотографировать/отсканировать. Да и быстрее.

Comment: А вообще-то оффтопик, если честно.

Comment: @VladD , написал выражения сюда (промежуточное и самое первое)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что надо иметь уважение к остальным и приводить читаемый текст, а не загигулины и каракули

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Построим таблицу истинности выражения `(!P -> Q) -> (P ^ Q) == (!P ^ !Q) v (P ^ Q)`:
`P Q Ans`
`0 0 1`
`0 1 0`
`1 0 0`
`1 1 1`
Тогда искомая [конъюнктивная нормальная форма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8A%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) равна `(!P v Q) ^ (P v !Q)`

**Способ без построения таблицы истинности:**
`(!P ^ !Q) v (P ^ Q) =`
`!P!Q + PQ =`
`(!P + PQ)(!Q + PQ) =`
`(!P + P)(!P + Q) * (!Q + P)(!Q + Q) =`
`(!P + Q) * (!Q + P) =`
`(!P v Q) ^ (!Q v P)`

Comment: То есть в таком случае надо полюбому строить таблицу истинности?

Comment: Да нет, не обязательно, просто это единственный способ, который я помню, к тому же тут переменных мало.

Comment: @MrShef, вспомнил способ без таблицы истинности.